# How do I patch a method of a property object in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I have a package that looks like this:

```
lcl
 |
 | - lcl
      | - LCL.py
      | - lunabuild.py
```

In the lunabuild module, there is a Lunabuild class.  The Lunabuild class has a method Lunabuild.configure_jobs().
The LCL class imports lunabuild:

```
from lcl import lunabuild
```

It then uses it as a lazily instantiated property:

```
@property
def luna_build(self):
  self._luna_build = lunabuild.Lunabuild()
```

the LCL class has a main() method that runs the Lunabuild.configure_jobs() method:

```
main(self)
  try:
    self.luna_build.configure_jobs()
  except ValidationError:
     ...
  except Exception, e:
     return_code = 2
     self.logger_exception(e)
```

I'm trying to patch configure_jobs to have a side_effect that raises an error, so that I can test that unknown errors are logged as expected.

I have been unable to figure out [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#id1).  it keeps telling me that it doesn't recognize the attribute, or that lunabuild has no configure_jobs attribute.

I've tried a bunch of different options.  Running with a debugger attached, I can see that test_lcl in the following code is an lcl.lunabuild.Lunabuild object

UPDATE: 
my latest attempt is

```
with patch.object('lcl.lunabuild.Lunabuild', 'configure_jobs') as mock:
  mock.side_effect = OSError(2, 'message')
  retcode = test_lcl.main()  
  self.assertEquals(retcode, 2)
```

Comment: Show us how you're patching it now and how that property is imported - the latter being very important to figuring out where to patch.

Comment: Added the info to the main.

Comment: Thanks for that, this adds a bit more to the puzzle.  Last bit:  you say that `Lunabuild` lives in that file structure.  Where are you invoking it?  Is it in the same module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way to do it is to path the static reference of `configure_jobs` method in `Lunabuild` class definition. So use follow code should do exactly what you need

```
with patch('lcl.lunabuild.Lunabuild.configure_jobs', side_effect=OSError(2, 'message')) as mock:
    retcode = test_lcl.main()  
    self.assertEquals(retcode, 2)
```

If you want patch just the object that you use in your test you can do it by:

```
with patch.object(test_lcl.luna_build, 'configure_jobs', side_effect = OSError(2, 'message')) as mock:
    retcode = test_lcl.main()  
    self.assertEquals(retcode, 2)
```

My taste is to use `patch.object` just when I have no other chance:

1. It is more complicated to understand what you are doing
2. To use it you should know more about objects to patch the right things